# XLRf - 1/4"m adapter with or without transformer

Tags: microphones

Greetings forumers from newbie!

Advice pls for selection of an adapter to plug a dynamic mic (ending in XLRm) into an active speaker ("karaoke) box with a "1/4f" input". Since the speaker box comes with a cheap mic with a cord ending in 1/4"m, should one presume that the box's single 1/4"f input is mic level? If so, should one presume that a XLRf - 1/4"m adapter without an inline transformer should work best since there seems to be no need to change a mic level signal throughout. FMI do I understand correctly that an XLRf - 1/4"m adapter with inline transformer is intended for cases where a mic signal needs to be stepped up for a line level input? For fuller context the application is for maximum portability of a saxophone busking using backing tracks from phone. Many thanks in advance.

https://en-us.sennheiser.com/instrument-microphone-saxophones-trumpets-drums-wind-instruments-congas-percussion-e-608 https://www.tronios.com/sps75-karaoke-machine-with-lightshow/

Answer (score 1):

Try the simple adapter.  When I started gigging, PA amps had Lo-Z and Hi-Z mic jacks.  But inputs on today's gear are very forgiving, a high input impedance with plenty of gain is typical and accepts most sources. The only Hi-Z input you're likely to see will be for a VERY high impedance source like a guitar pickup.   For the price of a simple adapter...

Love the 'light show'!

Answer (score 0):

More often than not, a mic equipped with a 1/4" jack is hiZ, and one equipped with an XLR is lowZ, the extra pin on the XLR used to produce a 'balanced line'.

Usually, when plugging a mic into an input, the resulting volume is more into the lowZ input. Often, either will work with either, but there can be volume and sometimes tonal issues.

Matching transformers are available either way, so your best bet is to take your stuff along to a sound/music shop, and they will supply you with the adapter which works best - or even another lead.